# Url Rewrite - regular Expression in IIS

Tags: regex, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

i have a url
www.example.com/test.aspx?n=quick-brown-fox-jumps-over-the--lazy-dog-2890

i want to display it as
www.example.com/test/quick-brown-fox-jumps-over-the--lazy-dog/2890

using URL Rewrite regular expression

please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /test/(.+)/(.+) /test.aspx?n=$1-$2 [QSA]
```

Comment: Must reload or restart your server after, did you do that ? I just tried it on my server (in local) and it works.